# Keyerror in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am getting keyerror in Pandas groupby function in which i am trying to group the column in `BU` with `Manager Index` and to get the average of Manager index in each group.

```
bu = new_csv.groupby('BU')['Manager Index'].mean()
bu.first()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some of the data you have in `new_csv` dataframe.

Comment: I think you're trying to do new_csv.groupby('BU').apply(lambda df: df['Manager Index'].mean())